# Django clear ManyToManyField associations on update

Tags: django, many-to-many

On update, I'm trying to clear all associations from a model having `ManyToMany` association with another. However, the associations are still persisted.

To explain my point, consider the following 2 models:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
```

Now, I wish to remove all associations of teacher to student, or vice-versa, whenever the shool changes for either model. So I decided to override the `save()` method for `Teacher` first.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
     ...
     ...
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          # after figuring out "school_id" changed
          self.students.remove()

          super(Teacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, once the `Teacher` object is persisted, I can see that all the `Student` associations are *reinserted* into the association table.

Am I missing out something here, or, is there some way to instruct the `models.Model.save()` not to reinsert the associations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `clear()` method not `remove()`. According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove),  `delete()` removes a specified model objects from the related object set

```
>>> b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
>>> e = Entry.objects.get(id=234)
>>> b.entry_set.remove(e) # Disassociates Entry e from Blog b.
```

But, that is not your case, you want to disassociate all of them not a specified one.

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # after figuring out "school_id" changed
      self.students.clear()

      super(Teacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether `remove()` really deletes objects. Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove). Also, I tried `clear()`, but that too didn't help.

Comment: remove() is used to disassociate one or multiples objects passed by parameter, clear(), disassociates all of them.

Comment: well _precisely_, but my point being that using either of them is not helping disassociate the references when an update occurs. The docs also say that both `clear()` and `remove()` do not require a `save()` to be invoked – but somehow Django is holding on to the references and reinserting them post-update.